# Switching window dedicate server

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, server, rackspace-cloud

I am currently using two dedicated window server 1 for development environment and 1 for production environment.

I am planning to change my server due to somewhat huge traffic and transaction load in MS SQL DB.

Can you suggest which one should i choose for Amazon EC2 or Rackspace?

Current configuration is like 8 GB RAM and 100 HDD of live.

Can anyone share his/her experience?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest AWS instead of Rackspace. This article is a good comparison and make lots of thing clear.

https://www.upguard.com/articles/aws-vs-rackspace-let-the-cloudwars-begin

Comment: Thanks for your answer we are planning to move only database to cloud now. SQL Azure